# Why cant i have a "equal" rational function

Tags: function, haskell, equality, haskell-platform

i am very new to the haskell and have a question about Eq.

```
data Rat = Rat Integer Integer

normaliseRat :: Rat -> Rat
normaliseRat (Rat x y)      
    |x < 0 && y < 0 = Rat (-x) (-y) 
    |otherwise = Rat (x `div`(gcd x y)) (y `div` (gcd x y))
```

So i have a func normaliseRat. And what i need is an instance of Eq and Ord. Of course, Rat 2 4 == Rat 1 2 should be valid.

Thanks for help

Comment: forgot to write  Rat (x y) == Rat (n m) = (x/y) == (n/m) thats how i tried to make an eq :( it was wrong as you might suggest

Comment: You can edit your question. But besides that, what is the problem? Have you tried writing the instances?

Comment: What's stopping you from writing `instance Eq Rat where (Rat x1 y1) == (Rat x2 y2) = ...` and `instance Ord Rat where compare (Rat x1 y1) (Rat x2 y2) = ...`?

Comment: @Noughtmare yes i have write it like this : instance Eq Rat where

Comment: @chepner i wrote them. the part i do have wrong is the part where you wrote"..."

Comment: `normalizeRat (Rat (-4) (-2))` seems like it probably gives the wrong answer with the obvious spec for `normalizeRat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell doesn't support *function* overloading. But `(==)` isn't a function; it's declared as a typeclass method, so any type-specific implementations of the method must be defined within an `instance` declaration, like so:

```
instance Eq Rat where
    (Rat x y) == (Rat n m) = x * m == y * n
```

(`x/y == n/m` is equivalent, after cross multiplying, to `x * m == y * n`; multiplication is more efficient and has none of accuracy issues that division would introduce.)

The same applies to `Ord`, except you have your choice of implementing `(<=)` or `compare`. (Given either of those, default definitions for the other comparison methods will work.)

```
instance Ord Rat where
    -- I leave fixing this to accommodate negative numbers
    -- correctly as an exercise.
    (Rat x y) <= (Rat n m) = (x * m) <= (y * n)
```

---

As a typeclass method, `(==)` is really an entire family of functions, indexed by the type it's being used with. The purpose of the `instance` declaration is not to redefine the method, but to *add* a new function to that family.

If you enable the `TypeApplications` extension, you can view `(==)` as a mapping from a type to a function.

```
> :t (==)
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
> :t (==) @Int
(==) @Int :: Int -> Int -> Bool
```

Without a type application, Haskell's type checker automatically figures out which function to use:

```
> (==) 'c' 'd'
False
> (==) 3 5
False
```

but you can be explicit:

```
> (==) @Char 'c 'd'
False
> (==) @Char 3 5

<interactive>:9:12: error:
    • No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal ‘3’
    • In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘3’
      In the expression: (==) @Char 3 5
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (==) @Char 3 5
```

Comment: when i wrote what you wrote there then i get an error. x * m == y *n i get "==" an error which says its an ambiguous occurrence

Comment: ahh, okayyy. So when i wrote my code should it look like this: (==) (Rat x y) (Rat m n) = x*m == y*n  ??

Comment: You shouldn't need to. I can't reproduce the error you claim to see.

Comment: sorry for taking your time. But i dont get it really. So when i write the code you wrote there, there shouldnt be any errors right?  But i get one because of the xm==yn

Comment: Are you sure you typed it *exactly* as shown? What's the *exact* error message?

Comment: instance Eq Rat where
  (Rat x y) (Rat n m) = x * m ==  y * n          //i wrote like that

Comment: You omitted the `==` from the left-hand side.

Comment: Your `Ord` definition requires a bit of care. If the rational hasn't been normalized, perhaps one of the denominators is negative (and not the other) -- then the `<=` has to become `>=`!